# Blazor Server - How to call a C# Method from Javascript in _Host.cshtml

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side

Good Day Everyone

Does everyone know how to call a C# method inside the MainLayout.cs from Javascript?
I'm trying to get a data from this when page is load

```
        [JSInvokable]
    public static int SessionTimeOut()
    {
        return 7000;
    }
```

I'm tried the solution on the internet but none of them work on me, I hope someone can help me on this.

Thanks everyone.